# How to Keep SQL Formatting of Date and Quotes in Excel CSV?

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to update a massive SQL table with thousands of rows and the best method I've come up with is a script that allows me to import a CSV file.

My problem is that after I export the original CSV file from the SQL and then edit it in Excel to add new values, it removes the quotations around all the values. (which I can see when opening the CSV in a TXT editor)

I found a solution on here using visual basic in Excel and the formula:
`for each v in range("A1:A1000") : v.value = CHR(34) & v.value & CHR(34) : next`

The problem is that this formula auto-formats my date fields... so I'll be left with "8/20/2018 20:21:02 AM" when I need to have the dates in the standard SQL format: 2018-08-20 20:21:02.

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, excel displays the date format based on your windows region and language settings, go there and try the change the format to what you need.

Comment: Why are you using Excel? You can update/append data with SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the way you open the file in excel
To open it properly, go to the data ribbon, choose import from text and on the wizard, make sure that the data type for the column is text

Another way to handle the issue is by a formula, on the converted datetime in excel format:

```
TEXT(cell-address, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
```

Comment: Im happy to hear :)